# Find inverse of specific matrix

Tags: matrices

So, I have to find an inverse of this matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
0 & C
\end{pmatrix}$$
where, $A\in M_m(\mathbb{R})$,$B\in M_{mn}(\mathbb{R})$, $C\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$
and $A$ and $C$ are both invertible.

I've tried $$\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1} & 0\\ 
0 & C^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

But it doesn't work

Comment: you mean $A$ and $C$ are invertible? an $m\times n$ matrix can't be invertible, unless $n=m$.

Comment: @Yanko, yeah, corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BC^{-1}\\ 
0 & C^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$

To come up with that I simply calculated the inverse of $$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ in the usual way.